# XSLT 2.0 - Regular expression infinite

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I have this string (virtually infinite):

[e00-100;e01-90;e02-0;e03-0;...;]

Now, I want this results:

e00-100

e01-90

e02-0

...

The string finish always with ;]

How do I do this with the regular expression (with the function `<xsl:analyze-string select="$string" regex="...">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>...`)?

Thanks at all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(replace(replace($string, '^\[', ''), ';\]$', ''), ';')" separator="&#10;&#10;"/>` it should suffice to output the tokens each on a line of its own.

If you want to wrap tokens as indicated in a comment then you can either use

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(replace(replace($string, '^\[', ''), ';\]$', ''), ';')">
  <val><xsl:value-of select="."/></val>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or analyze-string e.g.

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$string" regex="(e[0-9]+-[0-9]+);">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <val><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></val>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Here is a complete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="string" select="'[e00-100;e01-90;e02-0;e03-0;]'"/>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <results>
    <result-tokenize>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(replace(replace($string, '^\[', ''), ';\]$', ''), ';')">
        <val><xsl:value-of select="."/></val>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </result-tokenize>
    <result-as>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$string" regex="(e[0-9]+-[0-9]+);">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <val><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></val>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>    
    </result-as>
  </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (tested with Saxon 9.5 HE) is

```
<results>
   <result-tokenize>
      <val>e00-100</val>
      <val>e01-90</val>
      <val>e02-0</val>
      <val>e03-0</val>
   </result-tokenize>
   <result-as>
      <val>e00-100</val>
      <val>e01-90</val>
      <val>e02-0</val>
      <val>e03-0</val>
   </result-as>
</results>
```

Comment: Your test is ok but I want my result separated:
Example: `<val>e00-100</val> <val>e01-90</val> ... `

Comment: If you want to wrap tokens into elements then you indeed need more code, I will edit the answer.

Comment: With <xsl:analyze-string ...> in "regex-group(1) print:

`e00-100e01-90e02-0e03-0`

Isn't there a metod that print:

`regex-group(1)=e00-100
 regex-gropu(2)=e01-90 ...` ?

Comment: I think my suggestions work, I will edit and post a complete example.